# Distortion from bridge driver

Tags: driver, sine, bridge

I am feeding a square wave signal into some NAND gates and then into an ICL7667 MOSFET driver, which in turn drives an LC circuit.
The enable is shown for reference, but if always on.
Trace 1 (yellow) shows the output of the driver and trace 2 (green) shows the signal between the inductor and the capacitor.
You can see in trace 2 that there is some distortion at the switching point of the input waveform.
What causes this and is there any way to fix it so that I get a clean sine wave?
[image: Circuit]
[image: Traces]

Comment: The LC circuit is not resonant at the frequency you are providing. Either change the frequency or the LC values. Run the circuit in a simulator to observe the results and allow you to tweak the variables.

Comment: Have you tried displaying (2) minus (1)? Then you'll see a a sinewave across the inductor. What L and C did you use?

Comment: @Kartman - I thought I was running the square wave generator at the LC resonant frequency, but I will double check. The C is actually a couple of capacitors and a trimmer and I was adjusting the trimmer to give me the greatest amplitude waveform ... which I assume will be when the square wave and LC resonant frequency are the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *You can see in trace 2 that there is some distortion at the switching
> point of the input waveform. What causes this and is there any way to
> fix it so that I get a clean sine wave?*

You are looking at the centre node of the L and C and it will be wobbled by the waveform at one of the outputs. In other words try displaying (2) minus (1). Then you'll see a a sinewave across the inductor. Well, it won't be perfect but it'll be much nice looking I think you'll agree.

Comment: Thanks Andy. I will give that a try.

Comment: That worked Andy. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Vernon as a matter of interest for me, what value inductor and capacitor did you use?

Comment: I was using a 750uH inductor and a 1nf + 820pf + trimmer.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I might tag that circuit onto the edge of a different design and mess with it because the drivers look good given your scope shots.

Comment: Last night I changed the circuit a bit and instead of driving the LC directly off the ICL7667, the 7667 now drives a pair of Si3590DV dual P&N mosfets. Still have some testing to do, but I am liking the change.

Comment: Yeah, bound to be a more powerful driver but I was impressed by the amplitude you got on the circuit in your question.